# htaccess redirect subfolder (and children) to different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do I configure .htaccess to redirect from **old.com/foo/bar** to **new.com/bar** (and also **old.com/foo** to **new.com**)?

I searched and tried a lot of different stuff around and nothing works. Either **old.com/foo/bar** -> **new.com/bar** works but **old.com/foo** gets redirected to **new.com/foo**, or **old.com/foo** -> **new.com** works but **old.com/foo/bar** does not redirect.

And also, should the .htaccess go in the **foo** folder or the **root** folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule from `/foo/.htaccess` of `old.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://new.com/$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: So I think that back reference in the substitution is going to be empty.

Comment: You're absolutely right.. I meant to use `$0` but typed `$1`